# Is DynamoDb an Object Oriented Database?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, object-oriented-database

I have searched at many places but still confused that is DynamoDb an Object oriented? or if no then which type of Database it is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what answer are you looking for.

`DynamoDB` is of [Type Key-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB) storage.

You can save objects in it using SDKs such as [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html) in Java.

Comment: what do you mean by type key value storage?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) and [dba stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-is-a-key-value-store-database) explains it